# How do I solve "Incorrect permission on/usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1(need to setuid root)"?

Tags: 18.04, authentication

I'm getting this error message:

```
"Incorrect permission on /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1(need to setuid root)"
```

Due to this problem I can't download any app.

Comment: Did you do something to your system just before this started to happen? If you strred your system with a `root` stick, playing whack-a-mole with the aftereffects isn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 36):

This is the solution I came up with and tried, and it seemed to work, not sure why the permissions changed on this file though.

```
sudo chmod 5755 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

I also saw a version that tried: `sudo chmod +s ...` I originally opted to mirror the other permissions for the files in `/usr/lib/policykit-1/`

- From @ericx see comments: Or, more correctly try: [Chmod 4755](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-4755/) and for an extra level for the paranoid try: [Chmod 4555](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-4555/)
- Read more about `polkit` on the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/polkit.8.html)

Comment: Thanks, sudo chmod 5755 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 is  secure. It worked for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly, should be flagged accepted!

Comment: Using permissions 5755 enables both the SUID bit and the Sticky bit (5 in binary is 101; so you can see it's setting two fields whereas 4 is just 100). There is no need for the Sticky bit. The correct permissions are just 4755 (which only sets SUID). Or you could be a wee bit more paranoid and change that to 4555 (removing write permissions altogether).

Comment: @ericx Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Worked for /usr/libexec/polkit-agent-helper-1. Wasn't let me use balenaEtcher to flash an SD card.