How do I solve "incorrect permissions on /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be root)"?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 on a HP AMD Ryzen laptop.
After a system update, this error started appearing whenever I try to update or install apps. Note that my error says "polkit-1" and NOT "policykit-1". Short of re-installing Ubuntu, is there anything I can do?
I tried
sudo chmod 5755 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1

but nothing changes.
I am the only user of this PC, and have only one login which has not changed.

see this question and its answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115061/how-do-i-solve-incorrect-permission-on-usr-lib-policykit-1-polkit-agent-helper
